# Let two divs have the same height

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-float, height

I have two divs like that:

```
<div id="div1">ABC</div>
<div id="div2">ABC DEF GHI JKL MNO</div>

#div1 {
    width: 50px;
    background-color: red;
    float: left;
}

#div2 {
    width: 50px;
    background-color: green;
    float: left;
}
```

And i'd like to make the height of div1 is the same height of div2.

How can i do? Thanks!

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hF72b/)

Comment: Set a static value for both `#div1, #div2{height: 20px;}`

Comment: No idea why this is down voted, the user explained his issue, provided a code, if there is any reason for your down vote than please comment after your vote

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/hF72b/1/)**

the simplest solution is to wrapper both the divs in a div and make it display flex;

html

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="div1">ABC</div>
    <div id="div2">ABC DEF GHI JKL MNO</div>
</div>
```

css

```
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
}
```

Comment: Yes, you are the best. I prefer your solution to that solution which added a large padding-bottom and a negative margin-bottom.

Answer (score 2):

With this your two div will get the same height (height of the biggest Div)

*(This code use JQuery)*

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var s1 = $('#div1').height();
    var s2 = $('#div2').height();

    if (s1 > s2)
        $('#div2').css('height', s1 + "px");
    else
        $('#div1').css('height', s2 + "px");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

With jquery you could do something like this:

```
var tallness = $("#div2").height();
$("#div1").height(tallness);
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hF72b/9/)

Answer (score 0):

If you mind old browser  *or oldish solid way to do this*  you can look at http://alistapart.com/article/fauxcolumns a classic that is now reliable for ages :) and fits to your needs since width of element is set.

A very old template still acurate using this method with a 3 col layout  : http://www.pixy.cz/blogg/clanky/css-3col-layout/  (no flex nor table nor js there ;) )